# JavaScript Recursive function > Where is this output value coming from?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, syntax

The following simple function takes in an array and a number, and essentially outputs that array's length * the number specified.

```
function sum(arr, n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
  }
}
```

If we call the following: `sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 3)`, we correctly get 9 as the final output value.
For exmaple:

```js
function sum(arr, n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
  }
}

console.log(sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 3))
```

Not sure I understand what is going on here though. Where is this final value getting stored? I can see that calling the function in the function and using decreasing values in each instance is essentially replacing a for loop, but without additional context I'd expect the output to either always return 0 or for the function to not work at all.

What hidden aspects are coming into play to make this return that desired value?

Comment: what makes *this return that desired value* is .... `return` statement

Comment: Instead of waiting for good explanation here, go watch some videos on recursion and try to understand it, then take a look at your example again. It might take you some time to grasp it, but you'll get it eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a logger and watch the algorithm's work.

```js
function sum(arr, n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    console.log(n, arr[n - 1]);
    return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
  }
}

console.log(sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 3))
```

Comment: That definitely helps to shed light on what the function is doing, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are no hidden aspects. This is a classic example of recursion. It has a *base case*:

```
if (n <= 0) {
    return 0;
}
```

... which kicks in when the array has no elements: in that case the sum is indeed zero.

And it is has the *recursive case* for when the array has one or more elements:

```
else {
    return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
}
```

Here we solve the problem for a shorter array (hence `n - 1`), and assuming its outcome is correct, we just need to *add* the value to it that was left out: `arr[n - 1]`. This is not necessarily zero. When the array has size 1, we get `0 + arr[0]` here.

Answer (score 0):

in the first loop when you call `sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 3)`
then your function is returning the following
`sum([2,3,4,5], 2) + 4`

in the second loop when you call `sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 2)` (which was returned in the first loop)
then your function is returning the following
`sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 1) + 3`

in the third loop when you call `sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 1)` (which was returned in the second loop)
then your function is returning the following
`sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 0) + 2`

in the fourth loop when you call `sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 0)` (which was returned in the third loop)
then your function is returning the following
`0`

so effectively, it is as though you are returning `0 + 2 + 3 + 4`

Comment: This is a really good explanation for a newbie such as myself. I wasn't considering all of the data that was getting passed through with each iteration so this was helpful.